# Android 2.2 readUTF() Socket Problem

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to create a Java Client-Server Program, where the Server is running on a Windows PC, and the Client is running on an Android 2.2 Phone.

The Connection is okay. Sending Data from the Phone to the PC works also fine.
Just receiving Data on the Phone crashes the program.

I am using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to read/write through the Socket.

```
    //Thread on the Phone
    public void run() {
    while (RUN) {

        if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                //Crash
                String text = dis.readUTF();
                myTextView.setText(text);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //ErrorHandling
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I want to receive a String from the server and then show it in a TextView.
Any Ideas? I am already setting this permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

do i need any other permissions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't set text on your UI if you're not in the UI thread.

do this...

add:

`Runnable showmessage = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                   myTextView.setText(membervariabletext);
            }
        };`

and from your thread, after the readUTF(), call "runOnUiThread(showmessage);"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling on that for quite some time. Is this the prefered way to do it? Why is it not possible to change the UI from another Thread? I am new to Android programming so maybe you have some information on that special topic?

Comment: yeah it's a rule to remember. (It's the same rule in Windows programming with C# and Visual Basic.) Google gives an example using a handler: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#threading

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that your Data Input Stream is initiated correctly:

`Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());`

Otherwise, here's a link for example code where someone uses InputStreamReader() and OutputStreamWriter() to make a server and client for Android.

https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

Comment: Thanks. The Data Input Stream is initiated correctly. I also tried it with the StreamReader -> same Error. The Error appears only when I send something from the PC to the Phone. Maybe it has something to do with the String Encoding? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I also found an example of someone using readUTF and writeUTF:  http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html

Comment: Data Input Stream uses Modified UTF-8, so I suppose ensure your PC server is sending that format:  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInput.html

Comment: I am trying now sending only an integer and it works fine, atleast the receiving part. It seems that the error happens when i try to set the TextView:   `int s = dis.read();
                    song.setText(Integer.toString(s));`

Comment: Hm I am going crazy. It seems i cant use: `TextView.setText("abcd")` in my Thread-run-loop. I am getting the Textview Object from my Activity class as Parameter and storing it in a Membervariable. I also included a Thread.sleep() in my loop without effect.

Comment: heh, I didn't notice that.. it's an ez problem to fix... I'll make another answer

Comment: Hm now i put everything in on class i have a member: `TextView song;` which is initialized at the end of the constructor: `song = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song);`  and then i want to change the text in my run-loop: `song.setText(dis.readUTF());`  --> Program crashes.