# Unable to send data from C# to Java (Android) program

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send data from a C#.NET (Windows Application) program to a Java (Android App) program and vice versa, via TCP connection through Wifi. Till now I am success to send data from Java to C#, but unable to do so from C# to Java.

Following is the Java code, I used to create a connection and receive data:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
DataInputStream socketInputStream;
while (true) {
        try {
            String localIPAddr = getLocalIPAddress();
            InetSocketAddress ipEndPoint = new InetSocketAddress(
                    InetAddress.getByName(localIPAddr), 8222);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.bind(ipEndPoint, 4);
            workerSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            socketInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                    workerSocket.getInputStream());
            inputText.setText(socketInputStream.readUTF());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Here `getLocalIPAddress()` method returns the IP Address of the Android Device.

Following is the C# code in Windows Application to connect to the Android's IP Address (192.168.1.6) and send data to it:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!clientSocket.Connected)
                    clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.6"), 8222);
                clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtInput.Text));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Well, client (C#) is failing to connect to the server (Java) That means data is not leaving from client. But it will, if it get connected. Please tell me what am I missing and where am I mistaken. :)

Comment: What exactly happens? Does the data leave the source computer? Does it arrive at the target?

Comment: Can you post your declaration for clientSocket?

Comment: Client (C#) is failing to connect to the server (Java) That means data is not leaving from client. But it will, if it get connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved this myself, but of course [Dilberted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799844/dilberted) has helped me a little bit. I thank him for what he has provided. :)

Check out the solved Java code below:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
Socket workerSocket;
DataInputStream socketInputStream;
try {
    if (serverSocket == null) {
        // No need to get local IP address and to bind InetSocketAddress.
        // Following single line make it very simple.
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8222, 4);
        workerSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    }
    // When data are accepted socketInputStream will be invoked.
    socketInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                workerSocket.getInputStream());

    /* Since data are accepted as byte, all of them will be collected in the
    following byte array which initialised with accepted data length. */
    byte[] rvdMsgByte = new byte[socketInputStream.available()];

    // Collecting data into byte array
    for (int i = 0; i < rvdMsgByte.length; i++)
        rvdMsgByte[i] = socketInputStream.readByte();

    // Converting collected data in byte array into String.
    String rvdMsgTxt = new String(rvdMsgByte);

    // Setting String to the text view.
    receivedMsg.setText(rvdMsgTxt);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Note that a separate thread is to be used to run this code in background.

Answer (score 1):

After you have launched your android app and it is connected to the wifi, did you try to do a ping to the ip where the application is launched.

```
ping 192.168.1.6
```

If the IP is accessible from the workstation where C# app is running, try to perform a telnet on the IP and Port of the android ip, to see whether it works or not.

```
telnet 192.168.1.6 8222
```

If either of the two steps fail then could be a problem in the wifi network. As i have noticed many times the firewall of the routers filters out all the ports except 8080 and 80. So you would need to open the ports on the router.

Comment: both `ping` and `telnet` are working. In command prompt, when it entered in `telnet` with IP Address, it showed nothing except a blinking cursor. I typed in it but nothing happened. Then I noticed, the app in Android Device (Java Code) is frozen. After closing it, `telnet` in cmd is also got closed. When debugged the Java code, realised that it is freezing at `workerSocket = serverSocket.accept();` line. `ping` has given results correctly. So it is working.

Comment: what is the exception thrown by the client? can you post the exception with the stack trace?

Comment: now we don't have to bother about those exception anymore. I got the solution myself and now it is receiving data from C#. But it is still freezing at last line: `inputText.setText(socketInputStream.readUTF())` and not moving ahead. If you can tell me how to set text to a TextView and get this working, I can post the answer myself. :)

Comment: Now just want to know how to get string from the bytes that sent by C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do this?

```
Runnable showmessage = new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
               myTextView.setText(membervariabletext); 
        } 
};
```

and from your thread, after the readUTF(), call

```
runOnUiThread(showmessage);
```

[Found this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399076/android-2-2-readutf-socket-problem)

Comment: Thanks for this one. It is very informative and I will implement it. I have already managed to get string from the received byte and set it to a textView without using Runnable. But now got another problem. I will solve it very soon and post it here. :)